# How do I add an image on click event - Contact form 7?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, animation, onclick, contact-form-7

Is it possible when someone selects an option in the checkbox (Contact form 7) to be shown the image associated with that field, e.g. when someone checks the "dog" field, a picture of a dog appears on the side?

Comment: Take a guide from this tutorial: https://tutorialdeep.com/knowhow/change-image-on-dropdown-select-option-jquery/. you need to play with onchange event and yes it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Totally depends on how you want to achieve this. How is the checkbox value linked to an image? Is the value of the select field an URL to the image? In that case, you could look for a change event on the select field and replace the HTML in your target.

In jQuery it could look like this:

```
jQuery('#select-id').change(function() {
 jQuery('#target-div').html('<img src="'+jQuery(this).val()+'">');
}
```